# Access MySQL connected to Ejabberd using asmack

Tags: android, mysql, ejabberd, asmack

I have a Ejabberd Server which is conencted to MySQL.

How can I access the database using aSmack library for Android?

Is it possible to directly access it or do I need some interface in between?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot directly access the database using the XMPP protocol (among other things for security reasons).